# Creating and Emailing a PDF via .Net Webpage

Tags: c#, .net, pdf

I have a project that requires me to create a webpage that would allow users to fill-in information in a web page, create a pdf of the information( could be the whole HTML ), and email the pdf to someone.

I'm using c# and .Net. Does anyone know of a way to do this or could point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

easy stuff: you need to configure your SMTP to send emails. Then use ASPOSE. This program does exactly that: creates PDFs and joins them together.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I have searched for a way to do this for myself and have not been able to find a way directly in .Net without the use of a 3rd party library.

Right now I am using a library called iTextSharp with pretty good success. http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/

Another one I have used in Classic ASP applications (that does have a .Net component, but is not free), that was really good is Web Super Goo's ABCPdf http://www.websupergoo.com/abcpdf-1.htm

Good luck.

Comment: +1 on itextsharp (open source). It supports converting an entire html into a pdf document that you can later attach to an email.

Comment: aye.  both do.   iTextSharp is a bit more complicated to get it to display correctly, however, I guess that's the trade-off :)